# PasswordSignInAsync returns null when attempting to Login

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, claims

I am using razor pages for the first time and I would like to try to implement identity for a school project. Identity is confusing and I would like some help to diagnose the problem here.

I am currently using visual studio 2022 , .NET6 ,razor pages , Identity and entity framework.

I am a beginner at razor pages.

Description of the problem:
This line of code returns null having the correct credentials of the user. The Email and password credentials are correct
`var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);`
result = null

**Error Message**
ArgumentNullException:Value cannot be Null. (Parameter 'Value')

**This is my login code**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                //Claim aclaim = new Claim("LoggedIn", Input.Email);
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UuU5.png)
**Error stack**

````
```    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'value')
   at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value, String valueType, String issuer, String originalIssuer, ClaimsIdentity subject, String propertyKey, String propertyValue)
   at System.Security.Claims.Claim..ctor(String type, String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`2.GenerateClaimsAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1.CreateAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(TUser user)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable`1 additionalClaims)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.SignInOrTwoFactorAsync(TUser user, Boolean isPersistent, String loginProvider, Boolean bypassTwoFactor)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(TUser user, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1.PasswordSignInAsync(String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean lockoutOnFailure)
   at InfocommSolutionsProject.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel.OnPostAsync(String returnUrl) in C:\Users\Zade\source\repos\InfocommSolutionsProject\InfocommSolutionsProject\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml.cs:line 117
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert[T](Object taskAsObject)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory.GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Execute(Object receiver, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeHandlerMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeNextPageFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow(PageHandlerExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)```
````

**Solutions that I have tried while searching the internet**

1. Security stamp is not null. It is filled in the database
2. Nothing is overriding the ID property ( I think )

**What I think is the problem** 
According to the error stack it says that my claims constructor is null.But I have not implemented any claims in my current project.Is there any way to disable the claims in identity framework.I would like to use roles instead.
Why is signinManager trying to access the claims constructor?
[Here is the claims constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim.-ctor?view=net-6.0)
It is strange as I have not implemented any claims in the project.

I have no roles , claims or any policies. I am still a little confused on how to implement it. If the problem does not get solved I will do the school project without identity due to time constraints.

How do I fix this problem?
If I must implement claims how should I implement it in razor pages? All the tutorials are on MVC.

Please help. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fixed the issue.
Apparently my accounts model contained username. That username was overriding identity preconfigured aspnetusers username column. I removed username from account models and added-migration and update-database.

Basically, account models username field overrode the pre-existing ASPNETUSER username column.